# jQuery - Load content to div without flashing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load content (from a php file that get lists from database) to a div. It has a 10 seconds loop. So on every 10 seconds, it checks the file and load content to div to show new lists if added. However, on every run, the div content flashes (appear and disappear). It seems so unprofessional.

```
setInterval(function(){ 

$("#messageshere").empty();
$("#messageshere").load("msgs.php");

}, 10000);
```

My question is, is there smarter way for doing the same thing, but without flashing ?

Comment: sure, don't empty it.  ???

Comment: Funny, but it adds more and more with same content on every load...

Comment: it shouldn't be. .load uses .html(), which replaces the existing contents with new contents.

Comment: This MIGHT be an issue of the content "lists" - you might try `var newc = $(data); $("#messageshere").html(newc);` IN a callback...perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a callback to show your message and empty your div only when you have your response. like this:

```
$('#messageshere').load('msgs.php', function(data) {
    $(this).empty() // also unnecessary
    $(this).html(data);
});
```

Comment: I like the callback idea; alternately `$(this).empty().html(data);` as well as `$(this).html("").html(data);` or as you state simply the last line...

Comment: `.load()` sets the HTML by itself. Why do it again in the callback?

Comment: @Barmar - yep, so the question of the comments remains from OP as to why it does not work...makes me wonder as well